# ListView inside a CardView of a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I want to create a multiple CardViews -- each has a different number of children rows -- inside a RecyclerView. I managed to do it with the CardsLib library. However it limits my min SDK users from 11 to 14. So is there any other way to do it?

That's my output so far with CardsLib that I'm trying to achieve without it

[image]

Comment: What about using an ExpandableListView?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Never tried it before, would it be able to give me the exact outcome from my code with cardslib?

Comment: Try. Google for ExpandableListView, first, to see if it does what you want. By watching your image, it seems to.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein awesome, managed to get it done. thanks man